# CakePHP check if a specific value is true from a Database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Good Afternoon, so I want to check if a specific value in my database is true on CakePHP.
        My SQL table is called Oral and looks like this

```
    ---------------------
    |PK|OralPresentation|
    ---------------------
    |1 |1               |
    ---------------------
```

So what I want to do in my controller is to check if that Value is OralPresentation is 1.
    I do so in the following code

```
            $OralStatus = $this->Submission->query("SELECT * FROM Oral;");
            //If Oral Presentations are activated
            if($OralStatus['0']['PK']['OralPresentation']==1)
            {
                $this->set('Istrue','true'); //Passing this information to the view.
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set('Istrue','false');
            }
        }
```

Now when I echo isTrue in my view it always return false despite the database table being 1.  Another Solution I have tried is in the IF statement

```
if($OralStatus['0']['PK']['OralPresentation'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the PK that you're trying to check, a handy way to do this would be to use `field`.

```
$this->Oral->id = 1;
$Istrue = $this->Oral->field('OralPresentation'); // value for pk 1
$this->set(compact('Istrue'));
```

[cake docs on field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field)

[php compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

Comment: So I would insert the code above the IF statement?
The first line states the position
In the second I am checking Oralpresentation at position 1 in the second line
I understand everything else but what does compact do?

Comment: Compact creates an array containing variables and their values.  So you would replace your `if` statement with `$this->set(compact('Istrue'));` to set the value of `$Istrue` for the view. Alternately, you could replace the if statement with `$this->set('Istrue', $Istrue);`.

Comment: I might have to keep the IF since I want to create a link in the view if it is true.  That is why I am passing the Value 
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Yes that's right.  To clarify, you are setting the value of the `$Istrue` variable by using `field`.  Then you just need to send it to the view so that you can determine if you need to create a link.  This is doing the same thing as what you're trying to do with your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $statusQuery = $this->Submission->query("SELECT * FROM oral WHERE PK = 1");
        $this->set('status',$statusQuery['0']['oral']['OralPresentation']);
        $status = $statusQuery['0']['oral']['OralPresentation'];
        if($status['0']['oral']['OralPresentation']==1)
        {
            $this->set('Istrue',$status);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->set('Istrue',$status);
        }
    }
```

After trying a couple of solution based on other work I already had this worked.  It is able to pass the value of the Database to the view